# Flex 3.5 - 100% Width Grid inside ApplicationControlBar

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I've got a really simple Grid inside an ApplicationControlBar:

```
<mx:Grid>
    <!--<mx:GridRow width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:GridItem colSpan="3">
            <mx:Text fontSize="18" color="#000000" text="Conferences"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
    -->     
    <mx:GridRow width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:HBox id="addedBtns">
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%">

        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%">
            <views:LanguageSelector id="langSelector" visible="false" />                
            <mx:LinkButton label="{ResourceUtil.getInstance().getString('bbb.mainToolbar.helpBtn')}" click="onHelpButtonClicked()"/>
            <mx:Button label="{ResourceUtil.getInstance().getString('bbb.mainToolbar.logoutBtn')}" id="btnLogout" 
                       toolTip="{ResourceUtil.getInstance().getString('bbb.mainToolbar.logoutBtn.toolTip')}" click="doLogout()"/>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

All I want to do Is make the Grid stretch 100% across the full width of the screen, however the above does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<mx:Grid width="100%">
```

Your code now makes the grid scale to the size of its children.
Setting the grid width to 100% will make it scale to the size of its container.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! New to Flex and spent considerable amount of time finding this solution.